# Multiple ID selectors aren't working

Tags: html, css

So i have two Divs like this:

```
<div id="first_content">
    <ul>
      <li>This</li>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>should</li>
      <li>be</li>
      <li>displayed</li>
      <li>in</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>line</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="second_content">
    <ul>
      <li>This</li>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>should</li>
      <li>be</li>
      <li>displayed</li>
      <li>in</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>line</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#first_content, #second_content ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#first_content, #second_content ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

It doesn't work (at least on firefox 34). Style applies only to one ID.

When i remove one of these ID selectors, another one works fine.

I guess it should work? what's wrong?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but your closing `<ul>` element is wrong. Should be `</ul>`

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer correct if it helped you solve the problem, so as it can help others later on. (not so much in this instance, but as a general rule)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
#first_content ul, #second_content ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#first_content ul li, #second_content ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

if you are trying to select the `ul`'s and `li`'s of both containers you need to specify this with both selectors.

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best of us!

Comment: On the assumtion `li` must follow `ul`, you can simplify `#first_content ul li, #second_content ul li ` to `#first_content li, #second_content li`, or even `[id*=_content] li` (the last is not recommended however)

Answer (score 3):

Basic CSS

```
.foo, .bar { ... }
```

are two separate selector chains. You have:

```
#first-content, #second_content ul
     ^--- applies to <div id="first-content">
                        ^^^^^^^^^^--- applies to any <ul> inside <div id="second-content">
```

`<div>` tags do not have a `list-style`, so your first rule doesn't do anything for the first `<div>` set.  For your other rule set, `display-inline` will apply to the parent div for `first-content`, and to the `<li>` tags in the `second-content` area.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some css:

```
#navcontainer ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

And some HTML:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

These should produce the desired effect. Source: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm

Answer (score 1):

Multiple id concatenation has never worked in Firefox. For example, I am using 67.0 (64-bit) and the following CSS works as intended:

```
#noDisplay {
   display: none;
}

#togForm {
   display: none;
}
```

...but if I concatenate that, as shown below, it does not work (one id working, the other not working), and this has always been the case.

```
#noDisplay,#togForm {
   display: none;
}
```

I know that sometimes the reason is because of conflicting entries, but **display: none** on its own? - Argue with that if you can!